# Making Android Swipe Activity smoother?

Tags: android, swipe

I'm on a project developing an android catalogue application which mainly uses Swipe Activities.
The application is built up with 7 fragments, on which LinearLayout background images (To be specific, they're 1280*752 png images) and some buttons are placed. On the emulator, it works perfectly. But the problem is that, when I test it on a real device, the swipe animation isn't just as smooth as i want. It stutters.

Comment: Have you checked ViewPager? It's super simple to implement and it's buttery smooth. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 0):

I imagine those `png`s are pretty slow to decode on the main thread - consider putting a placeholder and loading them on a different thread.

That said, do not do this without profiling first! I could be completely wrong!

Run your app through [Traceview](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and see what's taking so long that it's making the animation jumpy.